# Why do we need to use nextLine() after every numerical input in java?

Tags: java, input

So I was solving the stdin and stdout II question on Hackerrank. Code attached below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        double d = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine(); 
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        //printing the output
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

And it always skipped the `String s = sc.nextLine();` if I did not use `sc.nextLine();` after every numerical input.
The only thing I know is that I have to add that line there. But I have no idea. Can anybody please explain to me why such aberrant behavior happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Thanks, it does answer my question.